# Speed up response time of application that uses web services

Tags: php, web-services

We have a small application that uses the Facebook API to retrieve the posts of an user that is logged with facebook and translate them using Bing Translate API. 
When you first login the server retrieves the first 10 posts, sends them to the Bing Api for translation and then sends them to the user. When the user scrolls to the bottom of the page using AJAX the server retrieves the next 10 posts and sends them to BING for translation and inserts them in the webpage.
The problem is that like this it takes a really long time for posts to load. Is there any way to speed up the process?
Using cache to store the next posts before acctualy being needed and loading them from the cache is an option?

include 'test_translate.php';
   function loadFirst($facebook){

```
$result = $facebook->api('/me/home?fields=from,type,story,message,picture,link,source,name,caption,description&limit=10' , 'GET');  
$posts = $result['data'];
parse_str($result['paging']['next']);
```

?>

class="post_paging">

```
<?php
$toTranslate = "";
foreach($posts as $post){



    $toTranslate.= "<div style=\"background-color:#72b0c9; margin:auto; padding-left:15px; padding-right:15px; padding-top:15px; padding-bottom:15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
     border-radius: 5px;\">
        <p><a target=\"_blank\" href = \"http://www.facebook.com/\"";

        $toTranslate.= $post['from']['id']."\">".$post['from']['name']."</a> </p>";


            if(isset($post['story']))
                $toTranslate .= "<p>" . $post['story'] . "</p>";
             if(isset($post['message']))
                $toTranslate .= "<p>" . $post['message'] . "</p>";
            if(isset($post['picture']))
                $toTranslate .= '<a target="_blank" href=' . $post['link'] . '><img src="' . $post['picture'] . '"/></a>';
            if(isset($post['name']))
                $toTranslate .= "<p>" . $post['name'] . "</p>";
            if(isset($post['caption']))
                $toTranslate .= "<p>" . $post['caption'] . "</p>";  
            if(isset($post['description']))
                $toTranslate .= "<p>" . $post['description'] . "</p>";




    $toTranslate.= "</div></br></br>";
}
$result = translate($toTranslate, 'it');

            echo $result;   
   echo "</div>";
```

}
?>

Comment: A *read-ahead* Cache sounds good. Do it. But also, find out *which part* is the slowest and see if that can't be improved for an immediate/easy speedup. It might be something surprisingly simple. Make sure that each actions (Facebook or Bing) only uses *one* batched request. Also, can the *client* initiate the Bing translation?

Comment: For each loading page we send only one request. Without the translation the loading time is about 3 seconds,  with translation is about 7-8 seconds for 10 posts.

Comment: That's a long time just to translate. It's only one translate request which is sent from the *server*, right? Does Bing have throttling or are these longer response times common? I would expect a "trivial-ish" web-service call to return within a second.

Comment: I don't really know why, only one request is sent, with the html containing all the posts.